# Test selector Plugin

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to follow the way as mentioned in wiki page. I am not aware of Json.
Just followed wiki page 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tests+Selector+Plugin

Have few queries . How to link your test case (either in java or python) to testcase mentioned in properties file? I plan to do it for python testcases.

Below is my properties file:

```
 tests=
 [{"enabled":true,"owner":"name","testgroup":"A","testcase":"NewTest.testCase1"},{"enabled":true,"owner":"name","testgroup":"B","testcase":"NewTest.testCase2"}]
enableField=enabled
groupBy=testgroup
fieldSeparator=.
showFields=testsuite,testcase
multiplicityField=multiplicity
```

NewTest is my class with testCase1 and testCase2 as methods.

In Jenkins , its listing as `Null.NewTest.testCase1` .
Obviously i missed something. Can someone explain how it works internally? how the class methods get called without explicitly creating class instance?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a testsuite. 
in your case "testsuite":"NewTest", "testcase":"testCase1"

Comment: thanks , i see now NewTest.testCase1. Next problem is , its not building any testcase.  So properties file is not able to resolve it. What am i missing here. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear, but I think I understand.
To answer how to link testcase in properties to actual python or java test . . .

The test selector provides the selected tests in a json array to other configured plugins which run in the Build part of job. The content of testcase or other vars needs to match what the configured test execution method expects.

e.g. the selected tests are provided in an environment variable to shell script if the Execute Shell method is configured to run in Build. "Choose tests for Environment variable TESTS :" $TESTS will be set containing the selection. $TESTS contains json style string of selected tests.

e.g.

1. in the testcase specify all that is needed for python test e.g. adding python test file something like "testcase":"path/test.py NewTest.testCase1"

e.g.

2. for jobs we have using shell script to execute tests we use separate testdir, testclass, testname. A test run script parses the json string and calls each python test to run and junit test results are generated and collected.

The properties file looks like this:

```
tests=[{"enabled":true,"owner":"OWN","testdir":"t/t/a","testfile":"test_a","testclass":"TestA","testname":"test_a","testcount":1},{"enabled":true,"owner":"OWN","testdir":"t/t/a","testfile":"test_b","testclass":"TestB","testname":"test_b","testcount":1}]
enableField=enabled
groupBy=testdir
showFields=testclass,testname
multiplicityField=testcount
fieldSeparator=.
```

And the TESTS var passed to shell script execution looks like this (of course with or without tests depending on what was selected):

```
'[{"enabled":true,"owner":"OMN","testdir":"t/t/a","testfile":"test_a","testclass":"TestA","testname":"test_a","testcount":"1"},{"enabled":true,"owner":"OMN","testdir":"t/t/b","testfile":"test_b","testclass":"TestB","testname":"test_b","testcount":"1"}]'
```